# Ice maker dispenses multiple cubes (2-3 stuck together)

Tags: refrigerator, ice-maker

This is a Whirlpool refrigerator.
Model # WRX735SDHZ
Serial # K80905198

The ice maker routinely dispenses multiple ice cubes frozen together. Sometimes 2, sometimes 3. This causes one or both of these problems:

1. Ice dispensing chute jammed. (Red Arrow)
2. Ice maker exit hole Jammed (Blue Arrow)

[image]

Both of these are fixable by manually breaking the offending cube clusters, but this happens 1-2 times a week and I'm worried that I'll break something trying to fix problem #2.

I've talked to Whirlpool, and their only solution was for me to have an Authorized Whirlpool Tech come out (from 122 miles away and at my expense!) to "have a look at it."

I'd simply like to reduce the amount of water being dispensed into the ice maker tray so that the cubes don't overflow slightly and freeze together.
I've considered trying to restrict the flow into the machine by the valve coming out of the wall that supplies water, but I assume that the ice maker has a sensor on it telling it when it's full, meaning that it will just flow until it's (over) full no matter how small a trickle is flowing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the fridge is level (in all three directions).  If it's not level, the water in the ice tray will also no be level.

Comment: I doubt their is any sensor, from my experience with ice makers they just run in a cycle, and the freezer triggers the inlet valve for a certain period of time expecting full pressure.  I'd try turning back the supply line shutoff valve to restrict the flow.

Comment: @raterus I cut it back a little, and will have to wait for a while to see if  it gets any better. Thanks!

Comment: @JPhi1618 I just checked the fridge, and it was *not* level, but then thought to check the ice-maker unit itself, and found it to be pretty level, close enough IMHO.

Comment: @Chowzen the fridge should be level so that the icemaker operates correctly... it may need that angle...

Comment: check the ice cube tray to make sure that it is not warped ... i had a similar problem with my ice maker ... the tray is made of plastic ... one end is attached to the motor, the other end is fixed ... the ice maker twists the tray to pop the cubes out .... the plastic tray got old and would not straighten out fully after being twisted ... the water would overflow the tray at one corner and drip onto the cubes in the bin below

Comment: how are the cubes frozen together? do they have little connector between them on the flat side, or are two cubes fused in a random fashion? If random, then you might have a leak in the bin; either warm air or liquid water can cause that to happen.

Comment: @dandavis They are frozen on the flat (top) side (exactly as if there was too much water pumped into the tray.)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same fridge and same problem. 3 cubes webbed together constantly. Jam at least once a week. Easy to fix by jabbing them to break them up. Usually 50 cubes fall to the floor because the tray is either overflowed or the chute is full from jam.  I took cover off and appears to be no water level adjustment (like many videos show). Fridge is level. Best fridge, worst ice maker.

Edit: after finding another video, I did notice the water level adjustment screw on right edge (near center). Need a really short screw driver. I adjusted ½ turn clockwise. Will see tomorrow if that worked.

Comment: Did that work? Can you supply a picture of said screw?

Answer (score 0):

Ice maker fill water by time. There is no sensor, so you may turn down wall vater valve or adjust water level screw in the ice maker.

Comment: You could improve your answer by citing a reference

Comment: This suggestion was supplied as a comment several years ago.